# How to make one AJAX request after a number of Backbone saves

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I have a situation where I need to save a Backbone model and then on its success iterate through a collection and save those and then on each of those successes iterate through another collection and save those and then after all those are complete perform one AJAX request.  This is what I have:

```
backboneModel.save(
    {},
    {
         wait: true,
         success: function (model1, response1)
         {
              $.each(backboneCollection1.models, function () {
                    this.save(
                        {},
                        {
                             wait: true,
                             success: function (model2, response2)
                             {
                                  $.each(backboneCollection2.models, function () {
                                       this.save(
                                           {},
                                           {
                                                wait: true,
                                                success: function (model2, response2)
                                                {
                                                     //If i put the AJAX request here it will happen for every iteration which is not desired
                                                }
                                           });
                                  });
                              }
                         });
               });
               //If i put the AJAX request here it will fire after one iteration of the first each even with async set to false on the AJAX request
         }
   });
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on where to perform this AJAX request so it only fires once after all of the backbone models have saved to the server?

Comment: I think the biggest problem is the structure is setup wrong.  For one, your last collection save will actually make N number of saves in magnitude of backboneCollection1.length.  So if collection1.length is 10 and collection2.length is 5 you will make 10 calls to save models in collection1 but make 50 calls to save only 5 models in collection2.  I am trying to get a solution to you that uses jQuery promises and do what you are trying but I am at work so it may be a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dCu2s/24/) I created.  It replaces your success callbacks and uses promises to save your model, then collection 1 and then collection 2. Once all of those are done you can make your ajax call in the done().

The bulk of the change is replace what you have above with this.

```
var saveEverything = backboneModel.save()
.pipe(function() { return saveCollection(backboneCollection1); })
.pipe(function() { return saveCollection(backboneCollection2); });
saveEverything.done(function() { console.log('done with everything, ajax time') });//make your ajax call in the done
```

If you have no idea what jQuery promises are, [this](http://terlson.blogspot.com/) is a really great blog post explaining promises.  If my example doesn't make any sense at all either just ask, I can try to explain what is going on and what is happening.

Comment: I never heard of promises before but the .pipe function seems like what I was looking for. The only problem is backboneCollection2 is a property of the models in backboneCollection1 thats why I'm nesting the saves. So when one model saves of collection 1 I get a certain property of that model and save everything in that collection...seems like it will be easy to do with what you posted thanks!!

Comment: Ah, didn't catch that backboneCollection2 is a property on backboneCollection1.  You should be able to use what I have but alter the second pipe to loop through backbonecollection1 and call the same method (saveCollection) and pass the nested backbonecollection.

Answer (score 0):

Do a count as you iterate through the models and when your count = the models length, call the AJAX

Comment: Keeping a count works fine but I was looking for more of something along the lines of the answer that fiskers7 posted..thanks for your help tho!